# Using "Advanced Custom Fields" checkbox fields in custom queries

Tags: checkbox, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress

I’m trying to write a WP_Query which uses some data from two ACF checkboxes as part of the arguments.

I found the documentation showing how to use fields in custom queries however I cannot work out what the correct syntax for my checkboxes is.

My ACF’s:

- Label: Promote to homepage?
- Name: promote_to_homepage
- Choices: Promoteto homepage : Promote to homepage
- Label: Make feature?
- Name: make_feature
- Choices: Show as feature : Show as feature (top of homepage)

This is the query I have:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(
   array
      (
         'posts_per_page' => 1,
         'meta_key' => 'promote_to_homepage',
         'meta_value' => 'Promote to homepage',
         'meta_key' => 'make_feature',
         'meta_value' => 'Make feature'
      )
);
```

I guess what I can’t figure out is why data is actually needed for `meta_key` and `meta_value`. Is the key the label? Is the value one of the choices? Or do I need to use `meta_value => true` or something? I have tried many variations and cannot get it to work.

Essentially what I want to do is output the most recent post that is checked for “Promote to homepage” and “Make feature”.

I have also tried:

```
array
   (
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'meta_key' => 'promote_to_homepage',
      'meta_value' => true,
      'meta_key' => 'make_feature',
      'meta_value' => true
)
```

**Edit**

This is the new code I have tried:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'promote_to_homepage',
                'value' => true,
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'make_feature',
                'value' => true,
            ),
        )
     );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

   if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
            echo '<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>';
            echo '<p><a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a></p>';
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post',   //replace 'post' with cpt if you need to.
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
 'meta_query' => array(
           'relation' => 'AND',
  array(
   'key' => 'promote_to_homepage',
   'value' => '1',
      'compare' => '=='
  ),
                array(
   'key' => 'make_feature',
   'value' => '1',
      'compare' => '=='
  ),
 )
 );
$the_query = new WP_Query($args); // This will return posts and other data
$the_query = get_posts( $args );  // This will return the posts
```

How's that for ya? Choose WP_Query **OR** get_posts: get_posts will return the posts data from wp_query anyway so you may as well just use that.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'true/yes' but you can play around with the values. If the key value in the custom field is literally 'true/yes' then you better have that as the value in the args - otherwise yes or true will do.

Comment: Thanks but I just can't get this working. It is just a standard post (not a CPT). Both values as shown above are ticked. True/yes was my example, not the name of the field. It seems `'value' = > true` simply doesn't work to pick up ticked checkboxes. I don't know what else to do if it's not possible to use ACF checkboxes in queries.

Comment: I got there in the end, but this was not correct. The comparison I had to use was "LIKE" and the value was the text choice set by the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```html
Another option is to get a lot of posts like this:

 $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'posts',
       );

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach($posts as $item) :
  $make_feature = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'make_feature', true );
  var_dump($make_feature); //test
  $promote_to_homepage = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'promote_to_homepage', true );
  var_dimp($promote_to_homepage); //test

  if(isset($make_feature) && isset($promote_to_homepage)):

    print_r($item);

  endif;

endforeach;
```

Check if this works first before limiting posts. If you don't get any results from var_dump variables, there's something up with ACF.

Comment: Does not work. I do not believe this answers the question. What is the `meta_value` and `meta_key` for ACF checkboxes? Is is the name and simply `true`? Is it the label? Is it one of the choices? What is supposed to go in the meta key when using ACF fields?

Comment: The meta key is the field name and the meta value is the input. Did you check my updated post on solution one?

Comment: Yes I have tried both your examples and neither work. When you say the meta value is the "input" does that mean `true` ? What is the input for a checkbox?

Comment: Yep. It would evaluate to 1 if true so the value would be "1" and you would check to see if it's equal to that. 

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/